# Ways of expressing the lack of ability to refrain from doing something

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What are the ways of expressing the lack of ability to refrain from doing something? The only one I've found is *help + ...ing*. For example:

> She can't help singing along when she hears this tune.

Obviously **She can't not sing** is incorrect, and **She is not able not to sing** sounds clumsy.

**Q1:** Are there other ways to express the same idea?

**Q2:** Does the following sentence sound natural? If not, how would you rephrase it?

> John can't help spoiling whatever he lays his hands on. (= It's an
>   inherent quality of John to  spoil everything (possibly involuntarily)
>   that he touches)

P.S. Couldn't figure out how to tag this question properly. Feel free to retag and remove this line.

Comment: I would say she _can't resist_ singing

Comment: "can't not-" is not incorrect. If you "can not-" that means you can avoid. if you can't avoid then you can't not.

Comment: None of the devices will bring about the same familiar sense of "can't help (but)". Sometimes, usage and idiom can take us where grammatical variations cannot.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 "*can't not*" is not suitable in writing, esp. formal writing.

Comment: @Kris: I'd say that depends on the writing. Certainly as it gets more formal you should avoid certain constructions. But it's certainly logically and grammatically correct on its own.

Comment: [Negative Polarity](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) would be a good tag. _Can help_ + V-_ing_ is [an NPI](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf).

Comment: I don't *mean* to...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could just add the word *but* (and drop the *-ing*):

> She can't help but sing along when she hears this tune.

Other common forms:

> She can't resist singing along.
>
> She can't resist the urge / compulsion to sing along.

In fact, *She can't help not sing along.* is acceptable in all but the most formal writing, but only use it when you wish to emphasise the point.  E.g.:

> A: Are you sure she wants to sing along?
>
> B: She can't help **not** sing along!

Comment: You can even go farther and drop "help."  Reading with and without the implied semantics: "She can't [do anything at all] but [to] sing along."  "She can't help [herself] but [to] sing along."

Answer (score 19):

What you're talking about sounds like a [compulsion](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/compulsion).

> **compulsion** *noun* the act of [compelling](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/compelling);  constraint; coercion.

Where something that is compelling has a "powerful and irresistible effect".

So you would say

> She is compelled to sing along when she hears this tune.

and

> John is compelled to spoil everything he lays his hands on.

If one feels compelled to do something then one is not acting voluntarily.

Comment: Or the variants 'She sings compulsively' or 'John compulsively spoils everything he lays his hands on'.

Answer (score 7):

Although Matt has the right answer with Compulsion, in informal speech, it is acceptable to say "she can't NOT sing". It is important to emphasise the "not" to clarify.

I would not use this in written work because it is too easy to misread.

Answer (score 1):

Among others, you can say:

> She can't stop singing when she hears that tune.

Although it would *seem* to mean that the tune only prevents her from ceasing to sing, it is used in practice to mean that she always sings whenever she hears the tune.

Answer (score 1):

Or "She can't keep from singing along."

Answer (score 0):

'She was helpless but to sing' is quite concise.